# GWT workflow with webdesign agency

Tags: gwt

what is the best way to create an GWT webapplication together with a webdesign agency?

I guess the webdesign agency will give ma a static html file + the css file. How should I integrate it with GWT? Should I use the .wrap() method of Button, ... ? Or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think that the first part is to identify which parts of the page are static and which parts of the page need GWT.

You will place their images in one or more [ClientBundle](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html) (it allows you to get all images in a single HTTP request).

You will place ther CSS in a [CSSResouce](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource).

By the way, you can also give them a link to the [GWT widget gallery](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefWidgetGallery.html) in order to give them an idea about what you can easily do.

Then, if they give you some static file, the easier way to integrate it is to work with [uiBinder](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) with the useful `<HTMLPanel>` tag which allows you to put pure HTML in your GWT app.

For example, if your agency gives you this HTML code with a text and a button:

```
<div><input type="button"/></div>
```

you can integrate this in uiBinder like this :

**MyComponent.ui.xml** :

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'>
  <g:HTMLPanel>
    <!-- replace <input type="button"> with the corresponding GWT component -->
    <div><g:Button ui:field="myButton"/></div>
  </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

**MyComponent.java** :

```
public class MyComponent extends Composite{

  public interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, MyComponent>{}

  //This allows you to get the button and work with it
  @UiField
  Button myButton;

  public MyComponent(){
    //use the .ui.xml file to get the HTMLPanel
    MyUiBinder uiBinder=GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);
    HTMLPanel panel = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);
    this.initWidget(panel);
  }

  //GWT sees the @UiHandler anotation and automatically adds a handler on "myButton".
  @UiHandler("myButton")
  public void onClickEvent(ClickEvent event){
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This answer is pretty good. You need to determine if your project is complicated enough for you to need GWT. GWT is for web applications, the kind that requires client/server communications. If you just want to have a pretty site with UI features, you can use a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. What do you think about this technique: http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/tags-first-gwt/ ?

Comment: The technique described in this article (put the whole HTML in a big String) is quite old. The article says `"GWT is working on a way around this which may be included in the 1.6 release"`. The current version of GWT is `2.5.1`. uiBinder is a far better technique and allows a good IDE (e.g. IntelliJ) to provide you with auto completion.

Comment: I think my webdesign agency will give me a .html and a .css file for the design. Then I need to rewrite the .html file into a uibinder.xml file, is that correct?